# Navbar with logo in left

Tags: html, css

https://codepen.io/f1rmeza/pen/BayxqWw

how i insert this logo into the navbar?

help me please i need to put logo in leftnavbar

im adding some more deitals for the post aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

follow the link to view the code

```
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Viga&display=swap');

*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/*Config da navbar*/
.navbar ul{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  background-color: #333;
  padding: 25px;
}

/*Config dos tópicos da navbar*/
.navbar li{
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0px 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.navbar li:before{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  bottom: -10px;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #f5b240;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.navbar li:hover:before{
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scaleX(0.5);
}

/*Config dos textos da navbar*/
.navbar a{
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Viga', sans-serif;
  padding: 0 20px;
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: Which logo are you talking about ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include your logo inside the ul element and set it to the left with `margin-right: auto`:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Viga&display=swap');

*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/*Config da navbar*/
.navbar ul{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  background-color: #333;
  padding: 25px;
}

/*Config dos tópicos da navbar*/
.navbar li{
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0px 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.navbar li:before{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  bottom: -10px;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #f5b240;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.navbar li:hover:before{
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scaleX(0.5);
}

/*Config dos textos da navbar*/
.navbar a{
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Viga', sans-serif;
  padding: 0 20px;
  color: white;
}

.navbar-logo{
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>NAVBAR CAIO</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="navbar">
      <ul>
        <img class="navbar-logo" src="https://spartanpower.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/Spartan-Power-Logo-512-50x50.png">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Serviços</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sobre</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contato</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: the HTML is invalid, ul can only contain li elements

Answer (score 1):

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Viga&display=swap');

*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/*Config da navbar*/
.navbar ul{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  background-color: #333;
  padding: 25px;
}

/*Config dos tópicos da navbar*/
.navbar li{
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0px 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.navbar li:before{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  bottom: -10px;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #f5b240;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.navbar li:hover:before{
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scaleX(0.5);
}

/*Config dos textos da navbar*/
.navbar a{
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Viga', sans-serif;
  padding: 0 20px;
  color: white;
}
.navbar-logo{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>NAVBAR CAIO</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <div class="navbar">
      <ul>
        <img class="navbar-logo" src="https://spartanpower.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/Spartan-Power-Logo-512-50x50.png">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Serviços</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sobre</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contato</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I moved the image in the list and then made the class you already named, instead of absolute you can switch it with fixed. You should cut out the white background of the logo tho.